# subdomain: cs, cstheory, or compsci ?

Tags: discussion, domain

Longer term (60 to 90 days) the goal is for the site to have a unique domain name, if it survives.

However, until then, it will be on a `*.stackexchange.com` subdomain. We have the following subdomains available:

- cs.stackexchange.com
- cstheory.stackexchange.com
- compsci.stackexchange.com

I, personally, think that **compsci** is the strongest of these three by far, even as a temporary 60-90 day placeholder.

Your thoughts?

Comment: another option would be theoryCS.

Answer (score 16):

I'm fine with cstheory, since compsci seems overly broad for the scope of this SE site.

Comment: I agree with Suresh. Without specifying 'theory,' the implication is too broad.